# How to reconnect to a child process after he is killed?

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

I have a nodejs child process working with three electron events, and I need it to finish after the second process, so I run child.kill, after child.kill I can't call the process again .. the following message appears: Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed.

Is there any way to let this process be killed to avoid excessive memory usage, but to be able to call again through an electron event?

Here is my code:

```
import { ipcMain } from 'electron'
import { fork } from 'child_process'

const child = fork('./child.js');

ipcMain.on('process', (event, arg) => {

     child.send({
      hello
     })

     child.on('message', (msg) => {
      event.reply('process-reply', msg);
     });
})`

ipcMain.on('process-2', (event, arg) => {
     child.send({
      hello2
     })

     child.on('message', (msg) => {
      event.reply('process2-reply', msg);
     });
})


ipcMain.on('cancel-process', (event, arg) => {
     child.kill();
})
```

Comment: `after child.kill I can't call the process again` -- because it is dead?

Comment: yeah, seems like stupid.. but i need to call these processes and end them multiple times without any memory problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, it's so much easier to i expected,
it was a scope problem, when i forked the child.js outside of ipcMain, he doesnt work at expected

here is:

```
ipcMain.on('process', (event, arg) => {
  const child = fork('./child.js');

  child.send({
   hello
  })

  child.on('message', (msg) => {
   event.reply('process-reply', msg);
  });

 ipcMain.on('process-2', (event, arg) => {
    child.send({
     hello2
    })

    child.on('message', (msg) => {
     event.reply('process2-reply', msg);
    });
 })

   ipcMain.on('cancel-process', (event, arg) => {
    child.kill();
   })
})`
```

thanks